# Should I daisy chain start connect or wire separately?

Tags: wiring, field, data-acquisition

This is related to field wiring schemes and interference. Sometimes tens of transducers are needed to be coupled to a single-ended data acquisition board's analog input channels **where the transducers are powered from a single power supply**. For instance the two [modules](https://www.dataforth.com/catalog/pdf/scm5b30_31.pdf)(it could be transducers) below are powered from one 5V power supply. And in this case as you see(upper left screw terminals) each modules are wired separately at their power terminals from the power supply.

[image]

Here below is a closer view where power terminals and the signal outputs to a DAQ is shown(Upper left two screw terminals on the modules are for power and upper right two screw terminals are for signal output coupled to the DAQ channels):

[image]

To make the question question more clear I draw the following different schemes:

[image]
(left-click to enlarge)

Tr0, Tr1, Tr2 are transducers, PSU is the power supply.

Currently the uploaded photos I guess show the Figure3 wiring configuration. In Figure1, +power terminals and the power grounds is daisy chained. In Figure2, only the +power terminals are daisy chained and the grounds are star connected.

(The signal ground and the power ground is connected on the [back panel](https://www.dataforth.com/catalog/pdf/SCMPB03and4.pdf) even though inside the module they are isolated.)

Which scheme would be more immune to interference and noise?

Comment: Fig 3 is best followed by Fig 2 then 1. But in order of increasing hassle to wire up it is reversed.